# Multiple audio players(Java or C++), that can be modified real-time

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, audiotrack, opensl

Looking for some help with audio playback on Android. We have an OpenGL app (Java + C++) and now we want to play sounds effects. Players should allow to modify playback rate and volume while playing.
Might be OpenSL or Audiotrack.

**First question?** *Is there any free or commercial library/wrapper that can do the thing?(might be java or native)*

..,if not, I'll explain what we made so far, and problems we experience.

We created MusicPlayer class (extends AsyncTask) with AudioTrack instance. In activity's onResume() we created 5 instances of it, executing it on thread pool. In task's *doInBackground()* we have a running loop checks states change, load files, and write to buffer. In JNI we have singleton that stores events queue and send them to java once per 10 miliseconds. It somehow works, but is rather far away from being acceptable. We experience following problems:

1. When file starts to play we can hear short noise on start. Like click or something.
2. Even if we flush or release AudioTrack it seems the sound plays in queue (especially when need to change buffers quick)
3. We can't create a loop in MODE_STREAM
4. When we modify AsyncTask's local variable CHANGE_RATE and RATE it should call audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(RATE). It does, but nothing happens.

I used to write in Obj-C for iOS and there are plenty "ready-to-use" solutions(e.g. cocoacontrols). Never thought dealing with sound on Android would be such a nightmare;/ Any help will be highly appreciated:)

Comment: _"We can't create a loop in MODE_STREAM"_ Why not? You're filling the buffers that you write to the `AudioTrack`. If you fill the buffers with the same PCM data over and over you'll hear the same PCM data over and over.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for response. Done it in similar way - it works now:) We also removed few first bytes, and we dont have clicks now. The main problem was that we send entire file to buffer at once. Now we splitted it for 3072b parts and it is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.0 or higher does not support playback rate control anymore. I'm not sure what was the reason for disabling it. I had to adopt [SOLA](http://www.surina.net/article/time-and-pitch-scaling.html) algorithm implemented by [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) library to add playback rate control to my app.

If you want to use it, you need to write a player using OpenSL. There are a lot of working examples around. Take the algorithms and use it for modifying PCM stream before sending the stream to the output sink.

*Update 22.01.2016:* Android appears to include [Sonic](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic) library into 6.0 release. Thus playback rate control should be available starting from Android M.

Comment: I tried with AudioTrack and it worked quite ok - no problems in changing playback rate. But I had to move from Java's AudioTrack to OpenSL for performance reasons. Different approach different problems:) Just made a new topic for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083874/opensl-audio-player-playback-rate-works-only-for-values-500-1000-2000

Comment: I use Sonic library in my app, which I mentioned in the post above. Here is a link to beta-community if you want to see how it sounds: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102599894094628040492